# Como fazer uma div ocupar a tela inteira, sobrepondo o elemento pai?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Eae galera blz. Estou precisando de uma ajuda com o seguinte efeito. Eu tenho um button que ao clicar ele abre uma lista. Porém eu quero que essa lista ocupe toda a tela. Só que ai que tem o problema, ao abrir ela simplesmente só vai ate o limite do elemento pai, não consigo definir o tamanho que faça ela cobrir toda pagina (body), ela simplesmente fica limitada ao elemento pai, teria como fazer algo para resolver isso ? estou utilizando o bootstrap.
Edit: tem como fazer sem o display fixed? para não ter a barra de rolagem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <!-- Meta tags Obrigatórias -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Olá, mundo!</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>


    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-6">
                <a class="btn btn-block nav-link" data-role="list">
                    <span>Open</span>
                </a>



                <ul class="list-unstyled bg-primary text-white" id="list">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-9">

                            <ul class="list-unstyled" id="list">
                                <li>
                                    <h3>teste1</h3>
                                    dassadasd dassadasd dassadasd dassadasd
                                </li>

                                <li>

                                    <h3>teste1</h3>
                                    dassadasd dassadasd dassadasd dassadasd
                                </li>


                                <li>
                                    <h3>teste1</h3>
                                    dassadasd dassadasd dassadasd dassadasd
                                </li>
                            </ul>

                        </div>

                        <div class="col-3">
                            <a class="btn btn-block pt-5 nav-link">Close</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </ul>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>




    <script>
        $("#list").hide();

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".nav-link").click(function() {
                $("#list").toggle();
            });
        });
    </script>



    <!-- JavaScript (Opcional) -->
    <!-- jQuery primeiro, depois Popper.js, depois Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: *"não consigo definir o tamanho que faça ela cobrir toda pagina"* se está dentro de outro div e quer fazer isso, não seria melhor abrir como uma lightbox e ocupar a tela toda? o jquery tem isso pronto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que desta forma que você está pensando não será possível, mas se mudar um pouco a forma de pensar já deverá obter o resultado desejado.

No lugar de "abre uma lista", você poderia

- Adicionar um elemento à DOM onde for necessário; ou
- Exibir um elemento anteriormente escondido; ou
- Deixar um elemento "vazio" preparado para receber o conteúdo que você quer e exibi-lo;

Todos os casos são semelhantes em termos de codificação. Segue um exemplo de como poderia ser feita a última opção.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="div_de_exemplo"></div>
    <a id="div_de_exemplo_close" style="display: none">close</a>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-6">
                <a class="btn btn-block nav-link" data-role="list" id="open">
                    <span>Open</span>
                </a>

                <ul class="list-unstyled bg-primary text-white" style="display: none">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-9">

                            <ul class="list-unstyled" id="list">
                                <li>
                                    <h3>teste1</h3>
                                    dassadasd dassadasd dassadasd dassadasd
                                </li>

                                <li>

                                    <h3>teste1</h3>
                                    dassadasd dassadasd dassadasd dassadasd
                                </li>


                                <li>
                                    <h3>teste1</h3>
                                    dassadasd dassadasd dassadasd dassadasd
                                </li>
                            </ul>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </ul>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>




    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#open").click(function() {
                $("#div_de_exemplo").html($( this ).next().html());
                $("#div_de_exemplo .ul").show();
                $("#div_de_exemplo").show();
                $("#div_de_exemplo_close").show();
                $("#open").hide();
            });
            
            $("#div_de_exemplo_close").click(function() {
                $("#div_de_exemplo_close").hide();
                $("#div_de_exemplo").hide();
                $("#div_de_exemplo").html("");
                $("#open").show();
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```